# Get the first string and compare in Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, regex

I have to compare the first string of the words which I get the value from other php file in ajax.

**AJAX**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#curr_add").click(function(e)  {   
        e.preventDefault();
        var curr_code = $("#curr_code").val();
        var curr_name = $("#curr_name").val();
        var curr_desc = $("#curr_desc").val();
        var curr_remark = $("#curr_remark").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "add_employee_currency.php",
            data: {
                data: curr_code,
                Cur_name : curr_name,
                Cur_desc : curr_desc,
                Cur_remark: curr_remark
            },
            success:  function(msg){
                //I have to split my msg string here before compare.

                if(msg == '"Error"'){       
                    $("#d1").html(msg); //show validation error in my modal dialogue
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#mainform").html(msg);   //display drop down list to my main form    
                    $('div#currency_modal').dialog('close');
                }

            },
            error:function(){
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $code = $_POST['data'];
    $name = $_POST['Cur_name'];
    $desc = $_POST['Cur_desc'];
    $remark = $_POST['Cur_remark'];

    $checkCurrencyCode = base_checkCurrencyCode($code);
    $checkCurrencyCode2 = base_checkLength($code, 3, 3);
    $checkCurrencyCode3 = base_generalValidate($code, 'alpha', 3);

    if($code == "")
    {       
        $err_code = "<br /><font color=red>".str_replace("##CONTENT##","Currency Code",ERR_BLANK_CONTENT_FIELD)."</font>";
    }
    elseif($checkCurrencyCode == false)
    {
        $err_code = "<br /><font color=red>".str_replace("##CONTENT##","Currency Code",ERR_CONTENT_EXISTS)."</font>";
    }
    elseif($checkCurrencyCode2 == false)
    {
        $err_code = "<br /><font color=red>".str_replace("##CONTENT##","Currency Code",ERR_CORRECT_FORMAT)."</font>";
    }
    elseif($checkCurrencyCode3 == false)
    {
        $err_code = "<br /><font color=red>".str_replace("##CONTENT##","Currency Code",ERR_CORRECT_FORMAT)."</font>";
    }

    if($name == "")
    {
        $err_name = "<br /><font color=red>".str_replace("##CONTENT##","Currency Name",ERR_BLANK_CONTENT_FIELD)."</font>";
    }

    if(($code != "") && ($checkCurrencyCode == true) && ($checkCurrencyCode2 == true) && ($checkCurrencyCode3 == true) && ($name  != ""))
    {
        $err_msg = base_add_Currency($code,$name,$desc,$remark);
        $success = "Success";
    }   
    if($success == "Success")
    {
        $dropdown = base_generateCurrencyDropdown($empCurrency,"estaf_emp_currency");//this query is shows out new currency drop down list in my main form
    }
    else
    {       
        //I have to split this with only show "ERROR" in order to compare in my AJAX
        echo json_encode("Error");
        echo "\n";
        echo $err_code ."\n".$err_name;
    }
?>
```

The output of my validation look likes this :

```
"Error"
* Please enter Currency Code. OR *Please enter your Currency Code in correct format.
* Please enter Currency Name.
```

I just want to get the **Error** in the above string in order to compare in my ajax

Comment: Comment these out?         // echo "\n";
        // echo $err_code ."\n".$err_name;

Comment: That's one of the way, but I have to show out validation error to user instead of just showing them **Error**. So I can't comment it, or is that other possible way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you just replace

```
if(msg == '"Error"'){       
  $("#d1").html(msg); //show validation error in my modal dialogue
}
```

with

```
if(msg.indexOf('"Error"') != -1){       
  $("#d1").html(msg); //show validation error in my modal dialogue
}
```

in your `success` function, essentially checking if your returned data contains the sting "Error" (with quotes)?

If you want to get even more specific, and say the "Error" **has** to be the first part of the string:

```
if (msg.indexOf('"Error"') == 0){
```

More information on .indexOf can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Answer (score 0):

Likely missing content type:

```
$aReturn[ 'error' ] = TRUE;
$aReturn[ 'error_code' ] = $err_code;
$aReturn[ 'error_name' ] = $err_name;
$sJson = json_encode( $aReturn, 1 );
header( 'Content-type', 'application/json' );
echo $sJson;
```